# Устаревшие (outdated) ответы

Tags: поддержка, ответы

Сейчас заметил такую фичу на en SO:

> "Is this answer outdated? Yes / No" ("Этот ответ устарел? Да / Нет").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде не было раньше?

Как это работает и будет ли внедрено у нас? Или я не заметил, что и на русском SO это есть?

Comment: Вроде бы об этом на [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/3240681).

Comment: Для меня полезность этой фичи сомнительна

Comment: @avp это когда на вопрос от 1700 года "на чём быстрее всего перемещаться" лучший ответ по-прежнему "лошадь", а не "ракета"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, и сейчас, в зависимости от окружающих условий, самым лучшим средством будет лошадь (но вы не сможете ей воспользоваться, поскольку навыки утеряны)

Comment: @avp вот значит в любом случае ответ устарел.